# CSS on I.E. 9 and lower (opacity)

Tags: opacity

My site [exerciserx.net](http://www.exerciserx.net) seems fine on Chrome/Mozilla but on I.E. 8 and lower its yucky (I know you have probably heard this before) but on I.E. 9 the navigation is completely dark on hover...I put all the necessary css (hoping..) but is there a way to get the site to look the same (or close to) on the other browsers? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

What you may need is PIE (http://css3pie.com/)  It has a lot of cool fixes for older versions of IE but be warned it may slow down your site in those browsers if too many styles are used.